# Why does it matter if I declare a boolean outside vs. inside this while loop?

Tags: java, loops, boolean

```
public class FindPrimes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Number_of_prime = 50;
        int number_of_final = 10;
        int count = 0;
        int number = 2;
        boolean isPrime = true;

        while (count < Number_of_prime) {
            for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= number / 2; divisor++) {
                if (number % divisor == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isPrime) {
                count++;
                if (count % number_of_final == 0)
                    System.out.println(number);
                else
                    System.out.print(number + " ");
            }
            number++;
        }
    }
}
```

The program should find the first 50 prime numbers. When I declare `boolean isPrime` outside of the `while` loop (example above) I only get the primes 2 and 3, but when I declare `boolean isPrime` inside the `while` loop, I get all 50 prime numbers.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What we see is you have declared `isPrime` inside `while` loop :|

Comment: Yes that correct as long as you are getting first fifty prime. What's wrong?

Comment: I reedit the the question.I declare boolean value outside while loop I get only 2 and 3.

Comment: This makes less sense now, the program should not be functional since you have defined it both inside and outside your while loop. Remove the Boolean declaration on the second isPrime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you're getting the right answer but you're not sure how/why it is.

Declaring `isPrime` outside of `while` does not work. Why? Because if you don't find a prime number within the loop, you set `isPrime` to `false` ...and you never reset it back to `true` ever again. Therefore, any subsequent numbers that come after the non-prime number would automatically default to a non-prime number.

Declaring `isPrime` inside of `while` works. Why? Because everytime you find a prime OR non-prime number, you will reset `isPrime` back to its original value and every subsequent number can and will be evaluated for its prime-ness accordingly.

Try drawing it out if you still have trouble understanding.

Hope that helps.